# BIND9 Forwarding by view

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, bind, internal-dns

Hi I think this is a simple issue, I'd like to forward only to certain IPs in the LAN network, for example I have 2 acl lists:

```
acl "office1" {
    192.168.1.15; // With internet access
};

acl "production" {
    192.168.1.101; // No internet access
};
```

I know that there probably should be more efficient ways to restrict internet access, but at the moment this is what I'd like to try.Here's what I've tried in `named.conf.local`

```
// Inlcude my acl definitions
include "/etc/bind/acls.conf";

view "no-internet" {
    match-clients { production; };
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
    zone "localdomain.com" {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/db.localdomain.com";
    };
    zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/db.192.168.1";
    };
}

view "internet" {
    match-clients { office1; };
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

    forwarders {
            201.56.59.14; // Made Up
            201.56.59.15; // Made Up
    };

    zone "localdomain.com" {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/db.localdomain.com";
    };

    zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/db.192.168.1";
    };
};
```

As you can see I want a `localdomain.com` defined for every computer in my network and forward  internet access to the computers in the office but not to the ones on the production floor.

---

I've modified my conf file, however the IP in the `"no-internet"` acl is able to resolve the domains, even though I've rebooted the computer, flushed the DNS using `ipconfig /flushdns` and set my DNS Server as the only one, why is this still happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have options in a view, you can however use the forwarders directly

```
view "internet" {
    match-clients { office1; };
    recursion no;
    forwarders {
            201.56.59.14; // Made Up
            201.56.59.15; // Made Up
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have a valid conf file, however computers in the production acl are still able to resolve domains appropriately and thus showing the websites any hints on that?.

Comment: Add recursion no; to the no-internet view